# Is it posssible to pagina DB::raw query? I am getting: Call to a member function paginate() on array

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel

Is it possible to make pagination on query like this DB::raw?    I have got same column names in tables witch i  am  joining. When i add paginate at the end i am getting "Call to a member function paginate() on array".

```
$basicQuery = DB::connection('mysql2')->select( 
            DB::raw(
                "
                SELECT
                `w`.`id`,
                `w`.`rodzaj`,
                `d`.`imie`,
                `d`.`nazwisko`,
                `d`.`firma`,
                `d`.`osoba`,
                `w`.`kwota`,
                `w`.`data`,
                `w`.`nazwa`,
                `p`.`nazwa` AS `partner`,
                `w`.`zmiana` AS `aktualizacja`,
                `s`.`status` AS `status`
            FROM `wniosek` AS `w`
            LEFT JOIN `dane` AS `d` ON `d`.`id` = `w`.`id`
            LEFT JOIN `partner` AS `p` ON `w`.`partner` = `p`.`id`
            LEFT JOIN `status` AS `s` ON `w`.`status` = `s`.`id`
            WHERE 
                `w`.`active` = '1'
            AND 
                `w`.`usun` = '0'
            ORDER BY 
                `w`.`data` DESC
            LIMIT 20"
            )
        );
```

Comment: have you tried `$basicQuery->paginate(5)` ?

Comment: Yes and get:
Call to a member function paginate() on array

Comment: oh then you need to convert this in Query builder instance

Comment: How to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you cannot do paginate in `array` so convert this Raw query in `Query Builder` like this

```php
$basicQuery = DB::connection('mysql2')
    ->table('wniosek')
    ->select(
        'wniosek.id',
        'wniosek.rodzaj',
        'dane.imie',
        'dane.nazwisko',
        'dane.firma',
        'dane.osoba',
        'wniosek.kwota',
        'wniosek.data',
        'wniosek.nazwa',
        'partner.nazwa AS partner',
        'wniosek.zmiana AS aktualizacja',
        'status.status AS status'
    )
    ->leftJoin('dane','wniosek.id','=', 'dane.id')
    ->leftJoin('partner','wniosek.partner','=', 'partner.id')
    ->leftJoin('status','wniosek.status','=', 'status.id')
    ->where([
        'wniosek.active'=>'1',
        'wniosek.usun'=>'0',
    ])
    ->orderByDesc('wniosek.usun')
    ->paginate(20);
```

then you can do paginate

ref links

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#introduction

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/pagination#paginating-query-builder-results